# Counter example related to spectral theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying linear algebra, and I got stuck in a situation. I know that by the spectral theorem, every Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized by an unitary matrix. But I have the following situation: consider the  complex number $z = a+ bi $ and the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} z & 0 \\0 & \bar{z} \end{pmatrix}$. Are these matrices unitary equivalent? I guess that this is a situation when we cannot use the spectral theorem, so I think it's false; but I can't prove that these matrices aren't equivalent.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: the first matrix you describe is not Hermitian.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Nor is the second.

Comment: @NateEldredge: unless b is zero

Comment: unless $z=0$. So, what is actually being asked here??? @Charles

Comment: I asked if the two matrix were unitary equivalent @IttayWeiss. Thank You for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spectral theorem actually applies to a larger class of matrices --- the [normal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). Since the first matrix in your question is normal (prove it!), it can be unitarily diagonalised to its eigenvalue matrix, which is precisely the second matrix in your question.